# Python script crashes when run via Cron

Tags: bash, cron, shell

I have a python script that completes exactly as expected when run manually as the root user.  When I put the script into cron.daily it crashes 100% of the time.

The error is a timeout error, but this question is not about troubleshooting the error directly.

Executing this works:

```
$ /etc/cron.daily/myscript
```

But it crashes when run automatically via cron.

**The Question:**  What is different about a root bash shell and the environment /etc/cron.daily executes in?

Answer (score 0):

Cron scripts run, by default, in a very minimal environment.  The exact set of variables, and their values, should be described in `crontab`(5) (the details vary by OS).